# Сегментация памяти. Формирование адреса

Tags: ассемблер

1. Верно ли, что в реальном режиме адрес вычисляется так:

`B8000` [адрес сегмента, с учётом сдвига в 4 бита]

+

`0000` [смещение]?

Как я понимаю, это физический адрес. В реальном режиме под сегмент отводится 64 КБ памяти, но всего адресовать можно 1 МБ. Значит, только первые 4 бита (`B` в `B800`) в адресе сегмента играют ключевую роль (позволяют перемещаться по этому 1 МБ памяти)?

2. При прямой записи в видеопамять мы обращаемся к сегменту `0xB800`. Но ведь копируя что-то в него, мы копируем в оперативную память, а не память видеоадаптера! Получается, в этой области оперативная память «пересекается» с памятью графического устройства. Или это не так?

Поясните, пожалуйста. И, если не затруднит, подскажите толковую литературу, где подробно расписаны эти тонкости. По теме пока нашёл только одну [страничку](http://asmforfun.blogspot.com/2009/05/blog-post_03.html), где рассказано про «20-битные» сегментные регистры.

UPD: Нашёл [таблицу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_memory#640_KB_barrier) на Википедии, указано, на что уходят блоки `A`-`F`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, по своему усмотрению можно использовать лишь 640 КБ из 1 МБ.

Comment: *В реальном режиме под сегмент отводится 64 КБ памяти, но всего адресовать можно 1 МБ.* - на 16битной архитектуре. *Значит, только первые 4 бита (B в B800) в адресе сегмента играют ключевую роль* - нет, весь адрес сегмента используется, просто на один и тот же адрес можно сослаться разными комбинациями сегмента и смещения. *Получается, в этой области оперативная память «пересекается» с памятью графического устройства.* - да, это проблема memory mapped i/o и печально известный [3gb barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier#Memory_mapped_I.2FO_and_disabled_RAM)

Comment: одним из каноничных эм произведений считается книга PC Assembly Book http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/

Comment: Про литературу не знаю. но на материнской плате еще куча управляющих микросхем (хотя сейчас большинство собраны в мосты). Через управление этими устройствами bios при начальной загрузке настраивает в каком диапазоне адресов шины располагаются реальные банки ОЗУ, а где располагается память или  даже порты ввода-вывода отраженные на память, других устройств

Comment: @etki, спасибо. Но вот эти 4 бита нельзя задать смещением - в этом помогают сегменты.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо.

Comment: Да, я неправильно вас понял, вы все верно написали.

Comment: @Андрей Дальше копать по ключевым словам "ACPI" (правда он много за что еще отвечает) "E820" - интерфейс BIOS для получения карты памяти. А дальше думаю надо уже конкретные контроллеры изучать. В архитектуре есть еще куча приколов. например по адресам A000 в реальном режиме обычно расположена  видеопамять для графических режимов. Но при переходе процессора в режим SMM логика материнской платы автоматически на этот регион мапит память SMM режима, которая более никаким образом не доступна.

Comment: @Mike, да уж, полно сюрпризов... Погуглил, E820 - довольно интересный интерфейс.